# Time between 2 actions

Tags: react-native, time

I am looking for a solution for having the time after an action.

For example time between the app start to charge and somebody clicking on a Button.

Is somebody can help me to understand how I can do that?

Comment: Save time stamps in the local database

Answer (score 0):

Using [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
let start = Date.now();
//Do something here
let end = Date.now();

let time = 'Milliseconds elapsed: ' + (end-start);
console.log(time);
```

Time will be in milliseconds so you can convert it to seconds or whatever you need.